# Select=*,PropertyName does not return the value for the PropertyName in Microsoft Graph api

Tags: odata, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

In Graph Explorer if i make a request to:

```
/v1.0/users/[User.Id]/drive/root/children?$select=*,sharepointIds
```

I do not get back the sharepointIds property from MS Graph.

If I remove `*` from select query parameter and only request `sharepointIds` property then I get the `sharepointIds` property and its values.

```
v1.0/users/[User.Id]/drive/root/children?$select=sharepointIds
```

I would expect `$select=*,sharepointIds` to return both the default properties and the `sharepointIds` in the same response.

Is there another working way for the clients to request additional properties from Microsoft Graph without typing all of the property names in the object one by one including the default properties?

The underlying OneDrive API seems to handle `select=*,[propertyName]` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible today. Microsoft Graph currently doesn't support wildcards in a `$select` query parameter. Each property you want to return must be explicitly listed in the `$select`.